# Vue class component 'super' must be called before accessing 'this' in the

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a `mixin` for paginations, but I need to set a module injected with `@Prop`.

How can I define a module inside my `mixin` if I can't access my component properties before calling super?

```js
export default class TableFooterComponent extends PaginationMixin {
@Prop({ required: true }) public readonly paginationModule!: Pagination;

 constructor() {
  super(this.paginationModule) // 'super' must be called before accessing 'this' in the 
 }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's possible but the only solution I see viable is to add the module to the constructor, but how?

If I'm missing something please point it out.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use component constructor for your own purposes unless you're sure you do the right thing, it doesn't fit the lifecycle. You didn't provide a mixin, I'm not sure how it's supposed to work together.

Comment: I know it's not the recommended design pattern but in this case (its really the only case that I use a constructor) it feels right. It would be overcomplicating a simples question to show you why I chose this architecture. But I do get your point and why you might feel that this is wrong.

Comment: If you want to extend PaginationMixin and use like that, it shouldn't accept constructor argument but be aware of paginationModule prop, that's it.